# Library in Objective C for OSX

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm creating a library for plotting a particular graph. How do I make it work in both ARC and MRC environment?

Comment: -ve voters... Reasons plz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Compiled* MRC/ARC code can be called from ARC/MRC code - ARC is essentially a compile-time technology which automatically inserts calls to the reference-counting memory management routines. At *runtime* ARC & MRC code interoperates without issue.

Therefore if you intend to ship your library in compiled form you can write it using either MRC or ARC and it can be used by both ARC & MRC projects.

If you intend to ship your library in source form then you can *[was "must", see edit below]* write it using MRC. Users can then incorporate your library code directly into MRC projects.

To include it in ARC projects users add the source as usual and then for each source file the file must be marked as using MRC. This is done by selecting the file in the Compiler Sources section of the Build Phases tab of the Project settings and adding the flag `-fno-objc-arc`. The flag instructs the compiler to compile that particular source file as MRC.

**Edit**

The above was over strong, in general with ARC being newer than MRC then requirement is to include MRC source in ARC projects, and this is done by flagging the individual MRC files with `-fno-objc-arc`. However the reverse is equally supported, you can include ARC source in an MRC project by flagging the individual ARC files with `-fobjc-arc`.

In other words, Xcode has a project-wide setting, "Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting" found in the "Build Settings" pane of the project settings, which sets whether the project is MRC/ARC; and this setting can be reversed for individual source files, in the "Compile Sources" section of the "Build Phases" pane of project settings.

The simplest choice is to distribute your library in binary (compiled) form, as this avoids the user setting any flags.

Answer (score 2):

You can define preprocessor macros for memory management calls that do nothing in ARC, and call the appropriate methods in MRC:

```
#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
# define ANRelease(obj)
# define ANAutorelease(obj) (obj)
# define ANRetain(obj) (obj)
#else
# define ANRelease(obj) [(obj) release]
# define ANAutorelease(obj) [(obj) autorelease]
# define ANRetain(obj) [(obj) retain]
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

If you choose to use ARC (advisable) you have a set of restrictions (for instance you cannot manually call any memory management method) that you can bypass only turning it off, which is not really an option because you would end up with memory leaks all over the codebase.

A reasonable way to go is to have two different versions, one with MRC and one with ARC, but it seems like an unnecessary effort.

Your users can import your ARC-based library into a non-ARC project by using the `-fobjc-arc` compiler flag.

Comment: I'd say it's more "You can, but you shouldn't"

Comment: Well you can't *make it work in both ARC and MRC*, given that my definition of *work* doesn't involve awful memory leaks ;)

Comment: I'll amend that - you can get it to "work" for some arbitrary definition of work.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella so does that mean i need to make two libraries. one for present mrc project and an ARC one for new projects that we will do?

Comment: Yes, that's a viable options even though I would just release and support an ARC version and instruct your users with MRC projects to link it with the `-fobjc-arc` flag.